# Attach an emacsclient to a specified running emacs server

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

Multiple  named emacs servers might be invoked by  the the commands

```
{ 
emacs --daemon="test1" 
emacs --daemon="test2" 
emacs  --daemon='test3"
} &> /dev/null
```

As there are three emacs server running on background,

How could attach an emacsclient to a specified one , saying "test2"?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html:

> The emacsclient program can specify a server by name, using the ‘-s’
>   or the ‘-f’ option (see emacsclient Options), depending on whether or
>   not the server uses a TCP socket (see TCP Emacs server).

Comment: emacsclient, not emacs